# To select an option in a dropdown and have other fields fill themselves in based on the selection

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm building an app.

I'd like to select an option in a drop-down and have other fields fill themselves in based on the selection.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> other fields fill themselves in based on the selection

Assuming, that `other fields` are fields of a record and the dropdown shares the same record's datasource I can suggest you populating their values in the `onValueEdit` event of your dropdown:

```javascript
var record = widget.datasource.item;

switch(newValue) {
  case 'xxx':
    record.FieldOne = 'Foo';
    record.FieldTwo = 3;
  break;

  case 'xxx':
    record.FieldOne = 'Bar';
    record.FieldTwo = 42;
  break;

  ...

  default:
     throw new Error('Caused by UFO');
}
```